# Adding string to output PHP file

Tags: php, imagettftext

So I have this code:

```
imagepng($image, 'Result.png');
```

It will create Result.png file in my server in the same folder

Now I wonder, how to create file like

```
Result123.png
Result1256.png
```

Both 123 and 1256 is a value of

```
$text
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do is:-

```
imagepng($image, "Result$text.png");
```

Note:- I assume that `$text` is a string variable containg different-different values every-time.

Comment: @HuỳnhLong  glad to help you :):)

Comment: OK. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

You can just do:

```
imagepng($image, 'Result' . $text . '.png');
```

Howerever, if you are allowing the user to enter the variable $text, this will be vulnerable to cross side scritping (XSS). In that case, use:

```
$newtext = strip_tags($text);
imagepng($image, 'Result' . $newtext . '.png');
```